# SQL Server Schema Compare via NUnit and use of scmp file

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, nunit

What I am trying to achieve is have a unit test run (via NUnit) to compare the schemas of two databases. Should the schemas of the databases be identical the test passes, if not the test fails.

So it appears that I can shell out to MsBuild to do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available.aspx

or parse the dacpac file:

[Can I automatically generate a change script using a .scmp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109794/can-i-automatically-generate-a-change-script-using-a-scmp-file)

However I am hoping there is something simpler than doing it the above ways to achieve this? Currently I do not have access to a CI to achieve this so for now it is unit test based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need some time ago, but I actually needed something that not only compared the two schemas but also automatically performed all changes to make them equal. I didn't find anything that met my needs, so I wrote [this tool](https://github.com/thiagotts/parilis). I've been using it both in production and development environments for several months now.

I believe you can use parilis to do what you want quite simply:

```
var database1 = new DatabaseDescription(connectionInfo1);
var database2 = new DatabaseDescription(connectionInfo2);

var parilis = new Parilis(database1, database2);
Assert.IsTrue(parilis.AreAlreadyEqual();)
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks exactly like what I need. I have had a go at using it, but have run into a few issues. I will post these on Git to avoid cluttering up this post.

Comment: The tool works as adevertised and Thiago has been very helpful in providing support and new features for our needs.